# Access vtkActor construction object and append new data

Tags: c++, vtk

I am working with VTK-6.1 and I want to create a single `vtkActor` using multiple `vtkUnstructuredGrid`. First I create the actor from a grid...

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> create_actor()
{
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkUnstructuredGrid> grid = create_grid_a();
    auto mapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkDataSetMapper>::New();
    mapper->SetInputData(grid);
    auto actor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
    actor->SetMapper(mapper);
    actor->GetProperty()->SetColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    actor->GetProperty()->SetEdgeVisibility(1);

    return actor;
}
```

and then I (try) to update actor using another grid:

```
void update_actor(<vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> actor)
{
    // get current grid
    vtkAlgorithm* algorithm = actor->GetMapper()->GetInputAlgorithm();
    actor_grid = dynamic_cast<vtkUnstructuredGrid>(algorithm);

    // create new grid
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkUnstructuredGrid> new_grid = create_grid_b();

    // combine grids
    auto append_filter = vtkSmartPointer<vtkAppendFilter>::New();
    append_filter->AddInputData(actor_grid);
    append_filter->AddInputData(new_grid);
    append_filter->Update();

    // update actor
    auto mapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkDataSetMapper>::New();
    mapper->SetInputData(append_filter->GetOutput());
    actor->SetMapper(mapper);
}
```

**The problem** is that the actor does not contain the combination of grids.

**Notes:**

(`create_grid_x()` functions are a little too complex to provide but they
certainly work because first actor is created correctly)

`SafeDownCast` as shown in [1](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Visualization/ReverseAccess) is not working too.

**References:**

[`vtkActor` reverse access](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Visualization/ReverseAccess)

[Appending data](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Filtering/AppendFilter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problematic section was the retrieval of `vtkUnstructuredGrid` from `vtkActor`.

```
// get current grid
vtkDataSet* actor_data = actor->getMapper()->GetInput();
```

...instead of using `vtkAlgorithm`